# How to set up ZoneAlarm firewall to work with WSL2?

Tags: firewall, windows-subsystem-for-linux, zonealarm

I have quite a typical issue - "network unreachable" in Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL2) with Ubuntu 18.04. There is much advice on the internet, what to do with `ifconfig` and `resolve.conf`, but they don't work. There are also some people who advise to turn off the firewall. **This helps**, but it's not the way I would like to go on.

So I tried to set up my free Zone Alarm Firewall. There is a new zone there, called "New Network", set as "Trusted", where the IP and the Subnet are the same as I see in `ipconfig` for "vEthernet (WSL)":

```
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.23.16.1
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.240.0
```

However, `ifconfig` in Ubuntu on WSL shows slightly different IP's

`inet 172.23.25.51  netmask 255.255.240.0  broadcast 172.23.31.255`

After each system restart, the IPs change (always starting from '172'), the netmask is the same.

What settings should I make in my ZoneAlarm to make this work?

Comment: WSL 2 uses Hyper V technology so it has a different IP address as it is effectively a different VM. Hyper V uses virtual network switches and adapters

Comment: Microsoft's built-in firewall has support for automatically working with WSL 2.  Other vendors do not, and from the issues on the WSL repo, third-party AV and firewall tools tend to be pretty broken with WSL.  If ZoneAlarm doesn't provide you with docs on how to do this, you're probably better off using the built-in firewall.

Answer (score -1):

So far the only solution I found is to make a VPN to my own server, and add this server to the firewall list of exceptions. Fortunately, I've been having a VPN server for quite a while :-)

I guess, running a VPN server on the Windows host machine would also work.